# Как нажать на JS кнопку через консольное приложение C# .NetCore?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Пишу **консольное** приложение на .Net Core, мне нужно открыть веб-страницу и нажать на ней JS кнопку по ID, как это сделать?

Comment: Никак? Там же gui нет. Или попробуй какой-нибудь селениум прикрутить...

Comment: Посмотри что происходит при нажатии кнопки. Если там обычный http запрос, то просто попробуй его сформировать и отправить.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Web Driver
http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/
Подойдет для этих целей